# Extracting a number from text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

"ROSTA Transfer from 02337358 to 00323594 with ref: 654712094032080" : I am try to extract only the ref 654712094032080 in a cell that contains "ROSTA Transfer from 02337358 to 00323594 with ref: 654712094032080". 
Note: that the 654712094032080 can be in any position but can always be identified with the number 654712.

Comment: If it can be in any position then you should share a few more examples. One example is not enough for anyone to identify the pattern (which will of course determine the required formula). Make sure to show enough examples to cover all possible positions/formats

Comment: the positions can be random as follows: 1)"ROSTA Transfer from 02337358 to 00323594 with ref: 654712094032080" 2)"ref: 654712094032080 for ROSTA Transfer from 02337358 to 00323594  " 3) "ROSTA Transfer from 02337358 to 00323594 external reference 654712094032080"... the only way to identify a reference is looking for the number in the cell that starts with 654712

Comment: the  only way to identify the reference  is looking for a number in the cell that starts with 654712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add a error handler since the methods used to extract the target string when it is in the end vs when your full string is in the start/middle are different.

- **When target string is at end:** Find `654712` and return that + everything after
- **When target string is not at the end:** Find `654712` and return that + everything after *up until the first space*

---

```
=IFERROR(MID(D9,FIND("654712",D9),FIND(" ",D9,FIND("654712",D9))-FIND("654712",D9)),MID(D9,FIND("654712",D9),LEN(D9)))
```

---

Comment: Hello Thank you so much... what if i wanted to do a further check by saying make sure this number is 17 digits

Comment: Well in your sample the numbers are only 15 digits. But, that deserves a new post. Share the formula you are using and show us some inputs with the expected outputs. 

If we allow the questions in one post to continuously evolve then no post would ever be solved. So, make a new post outlining your new request and I or someone else will surely help. As I sated above, **show examples**. Photos are often better than words in these cases (for me at least)